# Some Questions before submitting an app to Apple store

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have developed an IOS application, and i have many questions to ask for you :

1. I have signed the app, with my own apple program account. And now my client wants that i give him the app to put it in the Apple Store, he gives to me his apple developer account.

   1.1 My question is : what should i to do to sign the app with my clients account ? shoul i create a certificate to this ? what are the information needed to create a certificate ? and should i create a provisioning profile ?
2. In the application, i am using ssl, should i do other things because i am using ssl ? if yes what are this things ? for information i am localized in France.
3. Also, i am using some functionality that i am not sure they will accepted by apple, for example in the hom page of my app, i have a button to acces in the web site of my client ( the web site is not optimized for iPhone), will apple reject my app for this ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: You might want to consider following the [App Store proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30702/app-stores).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of answers:

1. You will have to sign the app with your client's credentials if you want to submit it to Apple through the client's account.  Your client will need to add you to their account as a team member. The process for setting up credentials and provisioning is the same process as when you set them up for your self.
2. need more info about exactly how you are using SSL and what for.
3. linking to a website (no matter how poorly suited for a device) is not a rejectable offence.

Comment: To add: I've done work for clients in the past. Essentially, you need their developer profile and a signing certificate from them. Then, once the app is signed, get their login and submit it through iTunes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For ssl i am using it when i call all my web services, the user need to authentificate with a user name and a password ( web services with https) and there many things for example geolocation, .... whi